# Shutdown VMware guest applications when UPS kicks in

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, ups, apc-powerchute

My situation is that I am running VMware workstation to run a LAMP server for some lightweight data collection.

My host OS is Windows XP.  I have a APC UPS that is set to shut down the PC via PowerChute if a power outage hits.

What I am wondering is if there is some way to gracefully shut down the LAMP server because I am pretty sure that VMware will keep PowerChute from shutting down the PC if there is a VMware appliance running.

Comment: Can you show me an example of the window that pops up when the PC is trying to shut down (The vmware one). IIRC it says something like **virtual machine still in use** but I need the exact text and I can make you an autohotkey script to close the virtual machine properly.

Comment: http://i33.tinypic.com/2z9mq77.jpg

Comment: Ah, thanks! Gonna need the file menu and shutdown dialog too (power off machine, send shutdown signal...) sorry for the hassle!

Comment: http://i35.tinypic.com/2rmo9co.jpg  -- Shut Down Guest is the option that must be used.
Followed by
http://i33.tinypic.com/snmpog.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow
WinWait,,virtual machine is in use,,,
{
    WinMaximize
    Send { Enter }
    Send { Alt } 
    Send { Right 3 }
    Send { Down }
    Send { Right }
    Send { Down 5 }
    Send { Enter }
    Sleep 5000
    Send { Enter }
}
```

You'll need to install [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com)

Comment: It worked first try? Even I'm surprised. You're very welcome :)